# Dbeaver failing to start ssh-keygen

Tags: ssh, dbeaver

I recently upgraded my ssh key to a ed25519 key and since then have been getting an error from Dbeaver saying that 'Cannot run program "ssh-keygen" error=13, Permission denied. Is this something new or is it a bug with the new key?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue for anyone stumbling across this was I had to switch the implementation setting from Jsch to SSHJ.

[image]